# Removing arbitrary line of text from a file with Python?

Tags: python

Given the following example file:

```
host wallmount {
    option root-path "iscsi:10.0.0.202::::iqn.2012-01.com.enactpc:storage.wall_mount";
    hardware ethernet 00:15:c5:71:b9:68;
    }

host netbook {
    option root-path "iscsi:10.0.0.202::::iqn.2012-01.com.enactpc:storage.netbook";
    hardware ethernet 00:21:70:bb:4e:95;
    }

host laptop {
    option root-path "iscsi:10.0.0.202::::iqn.2012-01.com.enactpc:storage.laptop";
    hardware ethernet 00:1b:38:4c:62:40;
    }
```

Would it be possible to take a known "hostname" (eg. "wallmount") and remove it's entire declaration automatically?

P.S. This is a DHCP config file under Linux...  I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. The *real* question is how smart you want it to be about it vs. how simple you want the code. For example: Should it deal with nested braces? Can braces be in a quoted string? Will the close brace always have a line of its own?

Comment: There is a possibility of nested braces in the future, but for now, the "sed" example will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with sed, which can be as simple as:

```
/host wallmount/,/}/ d
```

This is not going to be completely robust (because it does not fully understand all the syntax that the real parser of your config probably does), but if your inputs are pretty regular as your example is, it should work fine.

In case you don't know sed, here's how you'd edit a file in place using the above command:

```
sed -i '/host wallmount/,/}/ d' thefile.cfg
```